# Show that if $(X,T_a) a \in A$ Hausdorff for every $a$ the Intersection topology is also hausdorf.

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $(X,T_a) a \in A$ Hausdorff for every $a$ the $(X,\bigcap_{ a\in A}  T_a)$ is also a Hausdorff.

Nnow since i dont know if $A$ the set of indices is finite. I cant take the intersections of those neighborhoods that satisfy Hausdorff property and construct the neighborhoods in  $(X,\bigcap_{ a\in A}  T_a)$ since if i take an infite intersection it might not be an open set.So im stuck.!!!( I know that the intersection of topologies is also a topology in X)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true, even if $A$ is of size $2$. A proof can be found here:

http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2007;task=show_msg;msg=3281.0001